# Create popup form dynamically by selecting a checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

```js
function msg()
{
  if (document.getElementById('c1').checked);
    alert("suggest an update");
  }
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" id="c1" onclick="msg()" name="like"/>
```

Comment: Would need more explanation of what you are trying to do. Like a sample in some other website

Comment: You can use javascript library like jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can do form popup in different ways, one of them is using jQuery

Here is an [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_popup) that does what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The following will generate a form with one text input element, quite easy to extend that to include many other elements. Can't give any examples of jquery 'cos I don't use it.

```
    <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
        function msg(e) {
            var id='bob';
            var el=e.target || e.srcElement;
            if( el.checked ){

                var cont=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];                  
                var form=addNode('form',{id:id},cont);
                    form.style.width='500px';
                    form.style.height='500px';
                    form.style.zIndex=10;
                    form.style.border='1px solid black';
                addNode('input',{type:'text',name:'fred'},form);
            }else{
                if( document.getElementById(id) ) document.getElementById(id).parentNode.removeChild( document.getElementById(id) );
            }
        }
        function addNode( t, a, p ) {
            var el = ( typeof( t )=='undefined' || t==null ) ? document.createElement( 'div' ) : document.createElement( t );
            for( var x in a ) if( a.hasOwnProperty( x ) && x!=='innerHTML' ) el.setAttribute( x, a[ x ] );
            if( a.hasOwnProperty('innerHTML') ) el.innerHTML=a.innerHTML;
            if( p!=null ) typeof( p )=='object' ? p.appendChild( el ) : document.getElementById( p ).appendChild( el );
            return el;
        }
/*
The addNode function:
First argument is the type of element you wish to add.
Second argument is an object literal containing properties for the element you wish to set.
Third argument is the parent node to which you wish to append the new element/node.
*/
    </script>


html
----
<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" id="c1" onclick="msg(event)" name="like"/>
```

Comment: thank you so much but when i uncheck the checkbox it should close

Comment: surely you can add that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Angularjs, I highly recommend [ngDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog). it's my favorite type of popup.
You just create an html file that will contain the content of your popup and create an instance of the dialog once the checkbox has been checked (you can watch the value change using [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange))